# Protect my OS and manage disk accessibility

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, security, operating-systems

So I installed two Windows OS on two different disks. They are on the same computer. One OS is thrown away OS used to run potentially dangerous applications. Another one is my main OS and I want to protect it as much as I can. So How can I make the partition of the main OS on different hard disk inaccessible to the second thrown away OS, but first OS can access the disk of the second OS with no problems?
I know it sounds really easy, but I can't find a reliable way to do it online.

Comment: I would run the throw away on a VM personally

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing it this way, disk encryption is the way to go. Use Bitlocker (available in Pro editions of Windows only) or VeraCrypt (works on all Windows editions, but is less user-friendly). Encrypt your "secure" OS and you're done. The other instance will still be able to damage the partition by writing data randomly, but it won't be able to read anything from it.

**The real solution** is to use a VM for this purpose (as also suggested by @SQLTemp in the comments) instead of dual booting.

- The throwaway OS is isolated inside the VM and doesn't even know something else exists on the disk.
- You don't have to reserve fixed amount of disk space for the throwaway machine, VM image will grow as needed.
- If malware damages the VM, you can restore it from a snapshot in under a minute.

You should consider disk encryption anyway. On modern hardware it basically doesn't affect performance, but still effectively protects against malicious actors who have physical access to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the proposed solution using a virtual machine you can use a esata expansion card and simply disconnect one drive or the other and control the boot process over the boot menu prompt in the BIOS.
Desktop computers can boot from drives connected to esata cards.

There is no solution to run both simultaneously because the rogue operating system has full physical access to the good one then.